# Polar Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm new to Mathematica 10 (half-a-month user). I'm looking for a function of polar decomposition but for now I cannot find it. Can anyone tell me about related functions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: from [tutorial/LinearAlgebra/MatrixManipulation.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/LinearAlgebra/MatrixManipulation.html), it says "Compute the polar decomposition of a matrix:" `{u, w, v} = SingularValueDecomposition[{{1, 1}, {1, I}}];
{u.ConjugateTranspose[v], v.w.ConjugateTranspose[v]} // RootReduce`

Answer (score 17):

As Nasser pointed out, the polar decomposition of a matrix is not pre-built into Mathematica, but it can be easily computed from the singular value decomposition. For reference, here is a method to do it:

```
polarDecomposition[m_] := {#.#3\[ConjugateTranspose], #3.#2.#3\[ConjugateTranspose]} & @@ SingularValueDecomposition[m];
```

This tests that it actually works:

```
{U, P} = polarDecomposition[RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, {10, 10}]];
UnitaryMatrixQ[U]
HermitianMatrixQ[P]
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[P]
```

producing

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: +1 but I suggest you rename `$PolarDecomposition`.  That naming convention is used for system parameters like `$Path` or `$Post`, and IMHO it should be reserved for such.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah, I know that J.M. tried to promote the use of `$` as a prefix for user-defined functions, but it does seem to clash with system stuff.

Comment: I tried the code and for my random values, `HermitianMatrixQ[P]` return `False`. But `P - Conjugate[Transpose[P]] // Chop` returned only zeros.

Comment: Really? I don't remember ever doing that convention except for constants, like `$defaultSetting` or some such.

Answer (score 5):

In the polar decomposition of the rectangular complex matrix $A_{m\times n}=UH$, ($m\geq n$), the unitary polar factor $U$ is unique if $A$ is non-singular. On the other hand, it is enough to compute $U$ since $H=U^*A$. Therefore, one approach is to apply iterative methods specially when working in high precision computing.

In what follows, I provide the Newton's iteration as simply as possible to calculate the unitary polar factor
$$U_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(U_k+U_k^{-*}\right),$$
wherein $U_0=A$, $U_k^{-*}=U_k^{{-}^{*}}$, $U_k^{-}$ is the pseudo-inverse, see e.g. Chapter 8 of [N.J. Higham, Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation, Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, Philadelphia, PA, USA, 2008.]

This can be done as

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SeedRandom[12345];
m = 1010; n = 1000;
A = RandomComplex[{-10. - I, 10. + I}, {m, n}];
Id = SparseArray[{i_, i_} -> 1., {n, n}];
max = 25;

k = 0; tolerance = 10^-6; R[0] = 1; U = A;
While[k < max && R[k] >= tolerance,
   {u = U; U1 = PseudoInverse[U]; U2 = ConjugateTranspose[U1];
    U = 1/2 (U + U2); 
    R[k + 1] = Norm[U - u, Infinity]/Norm[U, Infinity]; 
    k++;}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

In the above code, I considered solving a complex random $1010\times 1000$ example, with the tolerance $10^{-6}$ while the maximum number of iterates set to 25.

To check the results, it is easy to observe that

```
H = Chop[ConjugateTranspose[U].A];
MatrixPlot[Chop[ConjugateTranspose[U].U]]
UnitaryMatrixQ[U]
PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ[H]

set = ScientificForm@Abs@N[Table[R[k], {k, 1, k}], 3]
Grid[{{"Number of iterations", (k)}, {"Stop termination", 
   ScientificForm@N[R[k], 3]},
  {"COC", 
   N[Log[Abs[R[k]]/Abs[R[k - 1]]]/Log[Abs[R[k - 1]]/Abs[R[k - 2]]], 
    3]}}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Here, COC is an approximate calculation of the rate of convergence which should be around 2.